# Package-lock.json - requires vs dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package-lock.json

In package-lock.json in dependency object, I have both `requires` and `dependencies` fields, e.g

```
  "requires": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.8.5",
    "rxjs": "6.2.2",
    "tree-kill": "1.2.0",
    "webpack-sources": "1.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": {
      "version": "6.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-6.2.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-0MI8+mkKAXZUF9vMrEoPnaoHkfzBPP4IGwUYRJhIRJF6/w3uByO1e91bEHn8zd43RdkTMKiooYKmwz7RH6zfOQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "tslib": "1.9.3"
      }
    }
  }
```

What is the difference between these two? Why some dependencies are listed in `requires`, other in `dependencies`, and some of them in both of these fields?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By default, npm installs all packages directly in `node_modules`.

However, let's say that package `X` is dependent on package `Z` in version 1.0 and package `Y` is dependent on the same package `Z`, but in version 2.0. In this case we have to install two versions of this package. One will be installed in root `node_modules` folder, and another one will be installed in `node_modules` folder of dependant package, e.g.

```
package.json
node_modules
    /X
    /Y
        /node_modules
            /Z@2.0
    /Z@1.0
```

Equally likely, npm could build a different, but [still correct](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/621733939456933888/npm-v7-series-why-keep-package-lockjson), package tree:

```
package.json
node_modules
    /X
        /node_modules
            /Z@1.0
    /Y
    /Z@2.0
```

The `package-lock.json` file will attempt to describe not only the dependencies of your project, but this tree structure as well. Which of the two trees above to build will be encoded in the JSON.

With this knowledge, it's easy to understand:

"requires" reflects dependencies from `package.json` file of this dependency, while `dependencies` reflects actually installed dependencies in node_modules folder of this dependency.

Comment: Compared to ruby's Gemfile.lock, allowing multiple versions of the same package to be used together is much more complex. It is a little difficult to justify its benefit.

Comment: Not needing a SAT solver to install packages safely is nice. Another win here is that installing a new package should never change the functionality of existing ones. Its all trade-offs.

Answer (score 30):

After reading the answers above, maybe I can put it more simply:

`requires` can be **shared** among all other top levels dependencies, while `dependencies` are **standalone**, belonging only to the module requiring them.

i.e.

`"@angular-devkit/core": "0.8.5"`,`"tree-kill": "1.2.0"`, and `"webpack-sources": "1.3.0"` do not belong **only** to the module. They are in the same level as the module requiring them. By contrast, `"rxjs": "6.2.2"` exists exclusively due to the module requiring it, and it is used only by that module.