# Understanding difference between 'requires' and 'dependencies' in package-lock.json

Tags: npm, angular-cli, package.json, package-lock.json

In order to understand difference between requires and dependencies in `package-lock.json`, I am checking the `@angular/cli` dependency object which looks as below.
Within `@angular/cli` the `uuid` package is listed with version `8.3.0` under  both `requires` and `dependencies` fields.

```
"@angular/cli": {
  "version": "10.1.7",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/cli/-/cli-10.1.7.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-0tbeHnPIzSV/z+KlZT7N2J1yMnwQi4xIxvbsANrLjoAxNssse84i9BDdMZYsPoV8wbzcDhFOtt5KmfTO0GIeYQ==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1001.7",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "10.1.7",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "10.1.7",
    "@schematics/angular": "10.1.7",
    "@schematics/update": "0.1001.7",
    "@yarnpkg/lockfile": "1.1.0",
    "ansi-colors": "4.1.1",
    "debug": "4.1.1",
    "ini": "1.3.5",
    "inquirer": "7.3.3",
    "npm-package-arg": "8.0.1",
    "npm-pick-manifest": "6.1.0",
    "open": "7.2.0",
    "pacote": "9.5.12",
    "read-package-tree": "5.3.1",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "semver": "7.3.2",
    "symbol-observable": "1.2.0",
    "universal-analytics": "0.4.23",
    "uuid": "8.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ansi-colors": {
      "version": "4.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-colors/-/ansi-colors-4.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-JoX0apGbHaUJBNl6yF+p6JAFYZ666/hhCGKN5t9QFjbJQKUU/g8MNbFDbvfrgKXvI1QpZplPOnwIo99lX/AAmA==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "debug": {
      "version": "4.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-4.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-pYAIzeRo8J6KPEaJ0VWOh5Pzkbw/RetuzehGM7QRRX5he4fPHx2rdKMB256ehJCkX+XRQm16eZLqLNS8RSZXZw==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "ms": "^2.1.1"
      }
    },
    "uuid": {
      "version": "8.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid/-/uuid-8.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-fX6Z5o4m6XsXBdli9g7DtWgAx+osMsRRZFKma1mIUsLCz6vRvv+pz5VNbyu9UEDzpMWulZfvpgb/cmDXVulYFQ==",
      "dev": true
    }
  }
```

I have gone through the [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926922/package-lock-json-requires-vs-dependencies) based upon which it makes sense to have `uuid` listed under `requires` and `dependencies` field if the version is different.

However, in this case `uuid` has same version `8.3.0` under `requires` and `dependencies` field. So, why it is required to be listed at both the places?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the relevant documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json), a `dependencies` entry is not only populated for a dependency with a different version than used elsewhere. It will also be populated if the dependency is not used anywhere else. At least, that's my interpretation. If I'm right about that, running `npm ls uuid` in your project should show that only one `uuid` entry.

It needs to be listed in both places because `dependencies` has much more information than `requires` and that information is needed by `npm`. The broader answer to "why", though, is "why not?" The `package-lock.json` file is for `npm` internal use. The format changed between npm version 6 and npm version 7. It will probably change again. They'll probably do whatever works best for the npm command-line tool. That may involve duplicating information.